# Flutter: unable to load PNG asset

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I need to use some density specific images in my flutter app, but unfortunately I faced with a problem while loading them.

I created several density specific directories for storing images according to official docs https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images, edited pubscpec.yaml and wrote some code.

Assets:

```
/assets
  /images
   /1.0x
     /qr_logo.png
   /1.5x
     /qr_logo.png
   /2.0x
     /qr_logo.png
   /3.0x
     /qr_logo.png
   /4.0x
     /qr_logo.png
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/strings/uk.json
    - assets/strings/ru.json
```

code:

```
GestureDetector(
     child: Container(
              width:120,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           color: Colors.black,
                           image: DecorationImage(
                               image:AssetImage('assets/images/qr_logo.png'),
                               fit:BoxFit.cover
                           ),
                       )
                   ),onTap:(){
                 print("CLICKED!");
               })
```

This results in:
he following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/qr_logo.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

> 0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
>
> 1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:44)
>
> 2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:449:14)
>   ...
>
> Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/qr_logo.png")
>   Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5e64b(), name: "assets/images/qr_logo.png", scale: 1.0)

Comment: i think you need to move image from `1.0x` to the `/assets
  /images` folder

Comment: @Eugene well, it works, but what image was used? from root folder or density specific one?

Comment: if you will read link you post above it says `The main asset is assumed to correspond to a resolution of 1.0`

Comment: @Eugene thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set `qr_logo.png` in `/assets/images` as baseline for [resolution-aware image assets](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#resolution-aware).